# Docker container error Waiting for headers

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

El error sucede cuando un contenedor de Docker no tiene acceso a internet y al estar "pelado"
sin casi ninguna aplicación, editor de texto, no se puede solucionar el problema por dentro.

Dejo la solución ya que me costo bastante trabajo encontrarla, al cabo de varias horas.

Answer (score 2):

**La solución es**:

```
docker-compose start  
docker network ls  
docker network host (Suele ser host después de realizar con LS)
```

La solución es bastante sencilla, pero al principio puede resultar confuso ya que se intenta realizar un `apt-get install` de alguna aplicación y se queda "tildado" con el mensaje 0% Waiting for headers.

Espero que a alguien mas le sea de utilidad :)